STLink v3 serial doesn't work
I'm trying without any success to get STLINK-V3MINIE serial to work. It shows up as a serial port on the laptop:
/dev/cu.usbmodem102
-------------------
Hardware ID: USB VID:PID=0483:3754 SER=### LOCATION=0-1
Description: STLINK-V3

But actually it doesn't send or receive data. First I tried to connect it to UART of an MCU that works for sure (checked with other USB-to-SERIAL device) - no data passes from the laptop to the MCU.
Then I tried to connect together RX and TX pins and send some characters from STM32CubeIDE - total silence. But this method still works well if I connect the USB-to-SERIAL device.
And also tried to connect it with RX/TX of the USB-to-SERIAL device - no results on sending or receiving anything.
So, maybe someone has had the similar issue and managed to fix it?

Did you connect grounds as well?

How exactly you have wired it to your target? Or when tested with TX/RX looped together? Do you apply VTarget reference voltage?

Yes, ground is connected, since both the STLink and the USB-Serial device are connected to the same laptop. Also tried to plug the ground pin of STLink explicitly. Regarding TX/RX loop - as well, TR plugged to RX. Maybe the STLink has burnt these pins, but it would be strange since they should be 5v tolerant

@Justme what do you mean by applying VTarget reference voltage?

@brigadir If it is a genuine ST link then it will require the MCU voltage from the MCU board to be able to communicate with it. If you did not give any Vtg supply to the ST-Link, it cannot communicate anything via any interface. Why it needs it? Because your MCU could be 3.3V or 2.5V or 1.8V and the ST-Link must use the same IO supply than your MCU. Now, did you simply connect TX and RX but did not have anything connected on Vtarget? If so, I will provide this as an answer.

@Justme you are right. What a weird issue! Additionally TX mark on STLink actually means RX :/ So, the correct connection is VCC, GND, TX<->TX, RX<->RX. Please add the answer to let me accept it. Thank you for this tip regarding VTarget

Reading the manual for the product reveals the following:
The largest issue is that the STLink  V3MINIE needs an external IO reference voltage to communicate with the target MCU at the same voltage, which the adapter does not know unless the Vtarget is connected.
Applying external supply such as 3V3 for the Vtarget reference will allow the loopback between TX and RX to work.
Additionally the pin named VCP_TX is an input so it connects to MCU TX and VCP_RX is an output so it connects to MCU RX.
